# Android countdown timer in service

Tags: android

I have count down timer in a service.
When I stop the service, will the countdown timer still count? I mean will its onFinished method will be called even if the service has been stopped?

Comment: Have you solved problem ?

Answer (score 2):

Countdown timer runs in a different thread and the callbacks are executed on the UI thread. Hence you need to manually cancel the timer whenever service is stopped. You can follow Hiren's answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
private CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer;
```

on **onCreate**:

```
mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(30000,1000) {

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

            // Your stuff
        }
    };

mCountDownTimer.start();
```

on **onDestroy**:

```
 @Override
 protected void onDestroy() {
    if(mCountDownTimer!=null){
            mCountDownTimer.cancel();
        }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

For **stop** service:

```
stopService(Your_Intent_For_Service);
```

**Done**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it would be called. You would end up leaking the service if the count down timer is not a static inner class